# Header Manager usage in Sampler

Tags: java

I have a jmx script in which I have a header manager for each soap request.
I want to extract the SOAPAction fields which has a value :**"http://****.svc"**
and give it as name to the http sampler.

Will i need to code to access it, if yes then how ?

Are header manager fields variables/properties which can be used ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to be [in scope of the requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) you would like to modify
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < sampler.getHeaderManager().size(); i++) {
       def header = sampler.getHeaderManager().getHeader(i)
       if (header.getName().equals('SOAPAction')) {
           prev.setSampleLabel(header.getValue())
           break
       }
   }
   ```
3. Enjoy

Comment: Could you please tell why we use pro processor and not pre processor here ?

Comment: Because you need Sampler to be **executed** prior to amending its label